# Symfony routing to WordPress' index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony

my following question is quiet stupid I think, but I couldn't find anything like this, which would have helped me... o.O

I want to create a route to my WordPress index.php and to wp-admin.

When somebody opens mywebsite.com/wordpress he should get redirected to the wordpress site. If one of the admins opens mywebsite.com/admin he should get to the login view of WordPress.

What do I have to do in routing.yml??

Thank you
Jannes

Comment: may be you do it in server config? something like this(nginx): `location = /wordpress {
     return 301 MY_WORDPRESS_INDEX;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_in_config.html